# Why does python setup.py bdist_wheel creates a build folder?

Tags: setuptools, distutils, python-packaging, python-wheel

I just learned to upload [my own python packages to PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/animalsay/) thanks to this amazing [tutorial.](https://realpython.com/pypi-publish-python-package/#configuring-your-package) I am trying now to better understand how `wheels` works and I found [this article](https://realpython.com/python-wheels/#setup) helpful.

However, I still do not understand why `python setup.py bdist_wheel` creates an almost empty directory named `build` with two subfolders: `bdist.win-amd64` (empty) and `lib` (which contains a copy of my package), in addition to the `.whl` file in the `dist` directory that developers will later upload to PyPI by doing `python -m twine upload dist/*`.

Why is this `build` directory necessary? I mean, would the `dist` directory not be enough? Moreover, why is the `.whl` called a *binary distribution* if the code is not actually compiled.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`python setup.py bdist_wheel` internally runs `python setup.py install` which in turn runs `python setup.py build` which compiles/builds the project into a temporary location inside `build/` directory and then installs compiled project into another temporary location inside `build/` directory. From files in that second temporary location it creates a wheel.

As for the compilation — python modules could be written in C/C++ and often they are. So `python setup.py build` needs to compile. If there is nothing to compile — well, the compilation step is skipped but the build step is still run.

Comment: Can you clarify the two subfolders within the build directory? How are they used in the process you describe?

Comment: For [Cheetah3](https://github.com/CheetahTemplate3/cheetah3) repo (I'm the current maintainer): after `python setup.py build` in the directory `build/` there are 3 subdirectories: `lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/`, `scripts-2.7/` and temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/`. After `python setup.py bdist_wheel` there is an additional subdir `bdist.linux-x86_64/`.

Comment: I meant, what is the use of these subdirectories you mention in the build process?

Comment: To allow builds in one blanket directory using different Python versions, to separate build phases.